# Convert AV1 container file to AV1 bitstream with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I want to extract AV1 bitstream from an AV1 container file(webm, mkv etc). For H264 files this command works:

```
ffmpeg -i trial.mp4 -c:v copy new.h264
```

But when same is used for AV1 bitstream:

```
ffmpeg -i trial.webm -c:v copy new.av1
```

It throws an error: **Unable to find suitable output format for 'new.av1'**

I tried vcodec copy as well, and getting the same result. Can anyone help me out in converting Av1 container to bitstream?

Answer (score 3):

AV1 bitstream can be muxed using the [OBU](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#obu) muxer.

```
ffmpeg -i trial.webm -c:v copy new.obu
```

Comment: Sorry I have very less information on AV1 but aren't OBUs combined to get AV1 bitstream?

Comment: Also this is not working for all AV1 container files. It worked for small 100 frames video. But anything large it doesn't work

Comment: Add report and return. Share report.

Comment: Log: https://sharetext.me/nzoghihxwi

Comment: The AV1 muxer is only available in current git builds.

Comment: Can you link source?

Comment: Source for what? I added this doc in Sep: http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#obu